# Probability question on 5 components operation after a given time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

My attempt:

$\lambda=1/2.5=0.4$

Since $P(T\geq t)=({1-e^{-\lambda t}})$

$P(T\geq3)=({1-e^{-0.4(3)}})^5$

---

However my book says:

$P(T\geq3)=({e^{-0.4(3)}})^5$

Why is this? How did the book do it. Is it a mistake by the book?

Comment: What happens with your $P(T\geq t)$ if $t$ grows large? Is that correct?

Comment: @drhab what do you mean? How will that change 1?

Comment: Always $t\rightarrow+\infty$ should imply $P(X\geq t)\rightarrow 0$. So your expression for $P(X\geq t)$ cannot be correct: if $t\rightarrow+\infty$ then $1-e^{-\lambda t}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @drhab But the cumulative distribution function of $P(X\geq t)$ is $1-e^{-t\lambda}$

Comment: Not $P(X\geq t)$ but $P(X\leq t)$ is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much :)